# Вывести информацию обо всех городах с указанием населения в единицах, сотнях и тысячах

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Код, 
       Название, 
       Область, 
       str([Количество жителей]/100) + ' сотен' as Количество_жителей
FROM Города
```

```
1   Москва  Московская      126780 сотен
2   Рязань  Рязанская         5269 сотен
3   Пермь   NULL         10553 сотен
4   Коломна Московская        1448 сотен
5   Луховицы    Московская         304 сотен
6   Рыбное  Рязанская          206 сотен
7   Самара  Самарская        11566 сотен
8   Калуга  Калужская         3288 сотен
9   Скопин  Рязанская          271 сотен
10  Ряжск   Рязанская          211 сотен
```

Так можно делать? Или это костыль и есть способ лучше?

Comment: *Так можно делать?* Зависит от СУБД. В одних можно, в других нет.

Comment: @Akina в sql server работает, ошибок не выдает. Просто сама конструкция смущает, вот и спрашиваю, не сделал ли я ерунды

Comment: SQL Server допускает использование оператора `+` для выполнения операции конкатенации. Но имхо лучше идти общим путём и использовать функцию `CONCAT()`. Равно как вместо специфической `STR()` использовать общие `ROUND()` и `CAST()` (опять же имхо).

Comment: @Akina понял, спасибо)